# Rails undefined method / cannot retrieve methods form a gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Not exactly sure where I am doing wrong, I'm following [this post](https://lob.com/blog/mail-a-physical-letter-in-ruby/) on how to set up the Lob gem with Ruby.

Currently my controller is as follows

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

    require 'lob'

    def index
        ....
    end

    def create
        ....
    end

    def show
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
        @result = User.return_representative(@user.address)

        ....

        Lob.api_key = 'test_my_api_key'  
        @lob = Lob.load

        @lob.letters.create(
          ....
        )
    end

    private

    ....
end
```

However, I'm getting an error message *undefined method `letters'*. Am I setting up the call incorrectly, or am I doing something else completely wrong? From the post linked above this does appear to be the way to set up the gem.

Edit: Running `@lob.methods` I get the following

> [:options, :options=, :areas, :addresses, :bank_accounts, :checks,
>   :countries, :jobs, :objects, :packagings, :postcards, :routes,
>   :services, :settings, :states, :base_url, :construct_url,
>   :format_address_params, :blank?, :present?, :presence, :psych_to_yaml,
>   :to_yaml, :to_yaml_properties, :acts_like?, :duplicable?, :deep_dup,
>   :itself, :try, :try!, :in?, :presence_in, :to_param, :to_query,
>   :instance_values, :instance_variable_names,
>   :to_json_with_active_support_encoder,
>   :to_json_without_active_support_encoder, :to_json, :as_json,
>   :with_options, :html_safe?, :`, :require_or_load, :require_dependency,
>   :load_dependency, :unloadable, :nil?, :===, :=~, :!~, :eql?, :hash,
>   :<=>, :class, :singleton_class, :clone, :dup, :taint, :tainted?,
>   :untaint, :untrust, :untrusted?, :trust, :freeze, :frozen?, :to_s,
>   :inspect, :methods, :singleton_methods, :protected_methods,
>   :private_methods, :public_methods, :instance_variables,
>   :instance_variable_get, :instance_variable_set,
>   :instance_variable_defined?, :remove_instance_variable, :instance_of?,
>   :kind_of?, :is_a?, :tap, :send, :public_send, :respond_to?, :extend,
>   :display, :method, :public_method, :singleton_method,
>   :define_singleton_method, :object_id, :to_enum, :enum_for, :gem,
>   :class_eval, :silence_warnings, :enable_warnings, :with_warnings,
>   :silence_stderr, :silence_stream, :suppress, :capture, :silence,
>   :quietly, :byebug, :debugger, :concern, :suppress_warnings, :==,
>   :equal?, :!, :!=, :instance_eval, :instance_exec, :**send**, :**id**]

Seems as if **letters** is not an available method. Does this mean the documentation is wrong?

Comment: could you add the result of @lob.methods to your question?

Comment: @SachinSingh I've added the result of `@lob.methods`. Seems like letters is not an available method. Does this mean the documentation is wrong?

Comment: do you have a address and letter model?

Comment: @SachinSingh I don't have an address model. Can you please explain why you think I might need one?

Comment: what is the version of 'lob' gem?

Comment: Have you tried adding the gem to your gemfile so that it's available everywhere, and then, in an initializer set its key ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out:

Maybe you have used different version of gem, i tried installing this gem and it worked for me.

```
sachin@sachin-laptop:~$ gem list lob

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

globalid (0.3.6, 0.3.5)
lob (2.4.0)
sachin@sachin-laptop:~$ irb
2.2.2 :001 > require 'lob'
 => true 
2.2.2 :002 > Lob.api_key = "test_00001"
 => "test_00001" 
2.2.2 :003 > @lob = Lob.load
 => #<Lob::V1::Resource:0x000000034e0a40 @options={:api_host=>"api.lob.com", :protocol=>"https", :api_version=>nil, :api_key=>"test_00001"}> 
2.2.2 :004 > @lob.letters
 => #<Lob::V1::Letter:0x0000000342de40 @resource=#<Lob::V1::Resource:0x000000034e0a40 @options={:api_host=>"api.lob.com", :protocol=>"https", :api_version=>nil, :api_key=>"test_00001"}>> 
2.2.2 :005 >
```

Comment: I specified the latest version of the gem and it worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Debug after the load to see if the method is actually there:

```
logger.debug( @lob.methods.sort )
```